# WFS reprojection problems

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, coordinate-system, wfs

In geoserver i have a layer in EPSG:4326.
In OpenLayers i add it on map as WFS:

```
            markerLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Markers',{
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
             version: "1.1.0",
            url:  "/geoserver/wfs",
            srsName:"EPSG:4326",
            featureType: "markers",
            featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
        }),
        projection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            externalGraphic: url_servlet+'img/marker.png',
            graphicWidth: 20, graphicHeight: 24, graphicYOffset: -24,
            title: '${tooltip}'
        })/*,
        eventListeners: {
                beforefeatureadded: function(e) {
                    e.feature.attributes.annotation =
                        window.prompt("annotation", "no comment");
                }
            }*/
    });
app.mapPanel.map.addLayers([markerLayer]);
```

My map in OL in EPSG:900913. So when i says to WFS projection=900913 i exepcted that features reproject and will show on my map. But its show somewhere outside OSM extent. And in WFS layer i see features with coords like this:

```
    POINT(62.01759636987174 56.767130970984326)
```

So how reproject wfs correctly?

**UPDATE**

I change protocol to HTTP and get gml:

```
            protocol:new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:markers&srsName=EPSG:900913&outputFormat=GML2",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML()
        }),
```

And now i get something interesting:
My layers and Google Base layer:
[image]

Same place with OSM base layer:

[image]

You see that there is no more red markers. And i have only question What a hell going on?

Comment: google support both 4326 and 900913 projection, so it can identify which proj it is. OSM base map (not osm as a whole) supports 900913 but your data is in 4326. thats why you will get atlantic ocean.

Comment: @byom: Its correct but i get not ocean. OSM shows nothing even on max zoom.

Comment: take out the line srsName:"EPSG:4326", which overrides the map projection in the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projection of the WFS vector layer needs to be set to the projection of the data. i.e 4326 and not 900913.

OpenLayers will reproject the data on-the-fly, if the projection of the Map and the Projection of the data have been set correctly.

Please see this working sample for more details:  [WFS Reprojection Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-reprojection.html)

The following sample code shows how you can have a simple map with just an OSM layer, and your WFS layer. Make sure that you point the proxy to your own properly configured proxy.

```
var map;

function init() {
    var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy_Open.cgi?url=";

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        projection: mercator,
        layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()],
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(21.2442, -28.464324)
        // Map uses web mercator as projection, so we have to
        // transform our coordinates
        .transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 10
        });

        var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.0.0",
            srsName: "EPSG:4326", // this is the default projection of the data
            featurePrefix: 'za',
            url:  "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "za_points"
              }),
            projection: geographic // specified because it is different than the map 
            });

    map.addLayer(wfs);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have specified the projection of layer as 900913, change it to 4326. you can define the map projection as 900913, and openlayers will reproject it.

Comment: I try but not help.